# How to plot two 3d perspective plots on the same figure without a gap in R?

Tags: r, rgl

I would like to plot a unit ball of a hierarchical group lasso penalty: Omgega(b) = w1*sqrt(b1^2+b2^2+b3^2) + w2*sqrt(b2^2+b3^2) + w3*sqrt(b3^2)=1.

```
require(rgl)
w=c(1,1,1)
## Plot unit ball in the 1st space sector (x>0, y>0, z>0)
leng <- 1000
b3.HGL <- seq(-1/sum(w), 1/sum(w), len=leng)
b2.HGL <- seq(-1/(w[1]+w[2]), 1/(w[1]+w[2]), len=leng)
b1.HGL <- matrix(NA, leng, leng)
for (i in 1:leng) {
for (j in 1:leng) {
    b1 <- (1 - w[3]*abs(b3.HGL[j]) - w[2]*sqrt(b2.HGL[i]^2 + b3.HGL[j]^2))^2/w[1]^2 - b2.HGL[i]^2 - b3.HGL[j]^2
    if (b1 >= 0) {
        b1.HGL[i,j] <- sqrt(b1)
    }
}
}
persp3d(b2.HGL, b3.HGL, b1.HGL, xlim=range(-1,1), ylim=range(-1,1),zlim=range(-1,1), col="#DF8585")
persp3d(b2.HGL, b3.HGL, -b1.HGL, xlim=range(-1,1), ylim=range(-1,1),zlim=range(-1,1), col="#DF8585", add=T)
```

I have been trying to plot two 3d perspective plots on the same figure with both connected smoothly (without a gap in between). I used persp3d function in {rgl} package in R. However, there is always a gap between the two perspective plots. What I want is a smooth curve. How could I make it happen? Any suggestion would be helpful! PS: Since my reputation score is not above 10, I cannot paste a figure now. Anyone who is kind enough please run the above codes in R and you will see what I mean by "gap". Here is the link for the image I want: [Image I Want](http://imgur.com/gallery/oIx9o6I)

Comment: "see the attached figure", paste a web link to the figure.

Comment: The advantage of `persp3d` is that you are able to interactively rotate the plots. If you wnat them side by side in a particular format then you should use ordinary `persp`.

Comment: @zx8754 Since my reputation is not high enough, Stackoverflow prevents me from pasting figures...and there is no available figures online since this is new...If you run the attached codes in R, you will be able to see the figure easily...Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I noticed the low reputation, hence suggested to put a web link to sites like imgur.

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks for the reminder. Here is the link of the image I want to have: http://imgur.com/gallery/oIx9o6I